# Firebase was cloned with another gmail account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, geofirestore

My Firebase account was cloned with another Gmail account. The Firestore in cloud function with all the information of my client account is now cloned to my personal account. I have two Firebase accounts, one is for my client, were all live data is present and the another account is for learning purposes, but today when I opened both accounts in a separate tab, the client data and everything in the Firebase  was incompletely cloned in my personal Firebase account also.

If I change a value in one of the Firebase accounts, it reflects on the other with the same value changed in the other account.

Answer (score 2):

On the Top menu bar there will be dropdown to select the current project. Make sure you have selected the correct project